# Merge two columns in Select into one column based on a condition

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssms

I have a `SELECT` with two columns I'd like to merge based on the condition that if the left one is null it should choose the right column but when the left column is not null it should always choose the left.

## scenario

What I have on the left is what I currently Have and I'd like to get the table on the right

AlphabetTable

```
+-------+------+    +---------+
| A     | B    |    | Desired |
+-------+------+    |---------+
| null  | 1    |    | 1       |
| null  | 1    |    | 1       |
|  2    | null |    | 2       |
|  2    | 3    |    | 2       |
|  2    | 5    |    |  2      |
|  null | null |    | null    |
+-------+------+    +---------+
```

## SQL for left table above

```
SELECT 
    CAST((select sum(Total) from LettersTable LT
                                WHERE LT.ID = ID
                                AND LT.Count > 5) 
                                AS INT) as A
    CAST((select sum(Total) from LettersTable LT
                                WHERE LT.ID = ID
                                AND LT.Count > 5) 
                                AS INT) as B
From IDTable
```

Heres what I have so far

```
SELECT 
        CASE WHEN
            CAST((select sum(Total) from LettersTable LT
                        WHERE LT.ID = AT.ID
                        AND LT.Count > 5) 
                        AS INT) IS NULL             
            THEN 
                (select sum(Total) from LettersTable LT
                        WHERE LT.ID = AT.ID
                        AND LT.Count > 5) 
                        AS INT)
            ELSE  
                (select sum(Total) from LettersTable LT
                        WHERE LT.ID = AT.ID
                        AND LT.Count > 5) 
                        AS INT)
 FROM AlphabetTable AT
```

Comment: The `COALESCE` function is your friend.

Comment: Your first query is non-sensical and will not return the values you have suggested.  First, the correlation clause is wrong.  Second, the correlated subqueries are the same.  The cast to `int` is also suspicious.

Comment: Can you create output table so it shows what you expect the output to be?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this with ISNULL Condition as shown below

```
    SELECT 
        CAST((select sum(Total) from LettersTable LT
                                    WHERE LT.ID = ID
                                    AND LT.Count > 5) 
                                    AS INT) as A,
        CAST((select sum(Total) from LettersTable LT
                                    WHERE LT.ID = ID
                                    AND LT.Count > 5) 
                                    AS INT) as B
    INTO #tmpIDTable
    From IDTable

    SELECT ISNULL(A,B) FROM #tmpIDTable
```

Answer (score 1):

here are a couple of options.. possibly

```
;with mycte as (
select null as a, 1 as b
union all
select null as a, 1 as b
union all
select 2 as a, null as b
union all
select 2 as a, 3 as b
union all
select 2 as a, 5 as b
union all
select null as a, null as b

)

Select 
*,
CONCAT(a,case when b is not null and a is not null then (select null) else b end) case_statement
,COALESCE (a,b)  coalesce_statement
 from mycte
```

Answer (score 1):

Assuming that you have the columns A and B available, one of the below should work:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN A IS NULL THEN B ELSE A END AS DESIRED_COL    
FROM
YOUR_TABLE;
```

Or as @NetMage suggested:

```
SELECT 
CASE WHEN (A IS NOT NULL OR B IS NOT NULL) THEN COALESCE(A,B) ELSE NULL END AS DESIRED_COL
FROM YOUR_TABLE;
```

Since COALESCE will throw an error if both columns are NULL, you would still require a case when to deal with that condition.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
;with mycte as (
select null as a, 1 as b
union all
select null as a, 1 as b
union all
select 2 as a, null as b
union all
select 2 as a, 3 as b
union all
select 2 as a, 5 as b
union all
select null as a, null as b

)
SELECT ISNULL(a,b) FROM mycte
```